# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.learning' has no attribute 'from_keras_model'

Tags: tensorflow-federated

Attempting to run federated learning on tff however, encountering the following:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.learning' has no attribute 'from_keras_model'

Code:
trainer = tff.learning.algorithms.build_weighted_fed_avg(
model_fn,
client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
)

state = trainer.initialize()
train_hist = []
for i in range(EPOCHS):
state, metrics = trainer.next(state, train_data)
train_hist.append(metrics)

```
print(f"\rRun {i+1}/{EPOCHS}", end="")
```

Environment:
Using Google collab
python - 3.10.12
TensorFlow Federated version: 0.61.0

Any help appreciated.

Attempted to downgrade version of TFF

Answer (score 0):

Now "from_keras_model" is moved to "models".
So "tff.learning.from_keras_model" is replaced with "tff.learning.models.from_keras_model"

Old Code

```
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model,
      input_spec=xxxxx,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
```

NEW Code

```
  return tff.learning.models.from_keras_model(
      keras_model,
      input_spec=xxxxx,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
```